# break; C++: which loop is it actually breaking

Tags: c++, c, loops, break

simple question regarding C++ code:

```
for(int i=0;i<npts;i++)
{
    for(int j=i;j<2*ndim;j++)
    {
        if(funcEvals[i]<bestListEval[j])
        {
            bestListEval[j] = funcEvals[i];
            for(int k=0;k<m_ndim;k++)
                bestList[j][k] = simplex[i][k]; 
            break; 
        }
    }
}
```

I want to ensure that

- Each line of `double **simplex` is inserted at most once in `double **bestList`
- The instance of `break` here breaks out of the second (inner) `for` loop.

Is this the case?

Comment: Yes, it is breaking out of the second `for` loop.

Comment: `break` always breaks out of the inner-most structure (loop or `switch`) active at that point in the code (in this case the `for (j ...` loop).

Comment: Break always breaks the innermost loop. If you want to break out of more than that you need to have a bool or something to keep track of when to continue or not.

Comment: The `break` statement will ALWAYS happen if `funcEvals[i]<bestListEval[j]` is `true`.  You really should use some better variable names.

Comment: Added "C" tag since the question is relevant to C and the code is written in C.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The break statement in C++ will break out of the for or switch statement in which the break is directly placed. It breaks the innermost structure (loop or switch). In this case:

```
    for(int i=0;i<npts;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i;j<2*ndim;j++)
        {
            if(funcEvals[i]<bestListEval[j])
            {
                bestListEval[j] = funcEvals[i];
                for(int k=0;k<m_ndim;k++)
                    bestList[j][k] = simplex[i][k]; 
                break; 
            }
        }
        // after the 'break' you will end up here
    }
```

There is no way in C++ to have break target any other loop. In order to break out of parent loops you need to use some other independent mechanism like triggering the end condition.

Also, if you want to exit more than one inner-loop you can extract that loops into a function. In C++ 11 lambdas can be used to do it in-place - so there will be no need to use *goto*.

Comment: A label and `goto` can often be used to break out of other loops.

Comment: I generally find it handiest to put this kind of thing in a function called something like `findFirstElemThatXYZ` and then return when I find it.

Answer (score 5):

The `break` statement in C++ will break out of the `for` or `switch` statement in which the `break` is directly placed.  In this case it will break out of the `for (int j = ...` loop.

There is no way in C++ to have `break` target any other loop.  In order to break out of parent loops you need to use some other independent mechanism like triggering the end condition.

```
// Causes the next iteration of the 'for (int i ...' loop to end the loop)
i = npts;

// Ends the 'for (int j ...' loop
break;
```

Comment: Don't forget about goto, exceptions and longjmp :)

Comment: setting `i=npts` to break the loop is confusing, use a boolean instead.

Comment: @MooingDuck my example is designed to be minimally invasive to the OP's sample.

Answer (score 3):

You are breaking out of your second loop to your first loop.

```
for (int i=0; i<npts; i++)
```

You could set a boolean at the top

```
bool shouldBreak = false;
```

and when you write break, write

```
shouldBreak = true;
break;
```

Then at the end of your loop, check each time,

```
if (shouldBreak) break;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < npts; i++)
```

You could set a boolean at the top

```
bool shouldBreak = false;
```

and when you want to break the other loop, write

```
shouldBreak = true;
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using `break`

`break` will break out of the whatever repeating or iterating loop that it's currently inside of. This verbose image guide is meant to highlight `break`'s behavior, not illustrate good coding practices. The inner for-loop would have sufficed, but like I said, this is for visual purposes:

[image: double-iterating-loops]

## Alternative Advice

Use Modern C++'s various search algorithms available in `<algorithm>` to search through containers and to a some extent, strings. The reason for this is two-fold:

1. Shorter and easier to read code
2. Usually just as fast if not faster than anything you could have written yourself

These code-samples will need the same boiler-plate, excepting `<algorithm>` for the older for-loop searches:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> int_container = { 10, 23, 10345, 432, 2356, 999, 1234, 0x45f };
bool has1234 = false;
```

The modern way would be something like this, where we quickly search through the container, and **if the search-iterator isn't at the very end of the container** (*not* the last element), **we know the value it's searching for was located**.

This code achieves the same result with less lines and less potential points-of-failure for user-written code, like the older alternatives below it.

#### Modern C++ style

```
auto search_position = std::find( int_container.begin(), int_container.end(), 1234 ) ;
if ( search_position != int_container.end() )
    has1234 = true;
```

#### C++11 range-based for-loop

```
for ( auto i : int_container )
{
    if ( i == 1234 )
    {
        has1234 = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

#### Old-school C-style for-loop:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < int_container.size(); i++ )
{
    if ( int_container[i] == 1234 )
    {
        has1234 = true;
        break;
    }
}
```